# Webpack generating large CSS files for IE9

Tags: angularjs, webpack, internet-explorer-9

For a day I have been struggling with a serious problem. I finished developing an Angular 1.5+Webpack(so everything is a component) application, and while everything is working as expected in Chrome/Firefox, when I went to IE9 everything broke apart. After some research I discovered the problem: my generated CSS was ~1Mb and so it surpasses the IE limit of ~4000 CSS rules.

These are some of the things I tried until now:

- Tried using [css-split-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/metalabdesign/css-split-webpack-plugin): does not even work, crashes when compiling.
- Removed source maps: it went down to 500 kbs (still not enough)
- Moved one external library to another webpack entry point: one CSS with ~130 kbs (OK) and another one with ~320 kbs (NOT OK).

Past this point, I reached a dead end

```
@import 'mixins';
@import 'variables';
@import 'multipurpose/multipurpose';

/* Component styles are injected through gulp */
/* inject:scss */
@import '../../components/advertising/advertising';
@import '../../components/cityforecast/city-forecast';
@import '../../components/cityforecast/weatherforecast/fivedays-forecast/fivedays-forecast';
/* endinject */
```

My components are dependent on the scss mixins,variables and multipurpose files and I don't know how I can separate these files even further. I guess one ideia would be to have all the components' CSS files as one entry point in Webpack, but that would be counter-productive and in time it would enter the "maximum-css-files-ie9-can-support" problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using [`code-spliting`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) which will load the components(should include css there) on demand

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran I tried your suggestion, and I did it for every component and their CSS(it works for the css only but it doesn't do much to help me). But if i try to do that when I'm including the components in the angular module it fails with "module 'undefined' is not available"

Comment: Can you show how did you do for components?

Comment: I used the fullstack-angular Yoeman generator, so the components are coded as described here: https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/templates/app/client/app/app.js

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 1,5 days struggling with this problem I have finally found the solution, and I will be forever grateful for the programmer who released this!

[BlessCSS Webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bless-css-webpack-plugin)

I was unaware of Bless and after finding out, I did a quick research on webpack, tried [also this one](https://github.com/BlessCSS/bless-webpack-plugin) but it didn't work.